# How can I not infringe on another game, while having a similar concept to that game?

Tags: copyright, storyboard

The Call Of Duty game (Black Ops) has its story revolving around number stations, Mk-ultra brainwashing, black operations and Soviet biochemical weapons. I want to have my story's concept pretty much similar like that with some differences, but I don't want to infringe on the original story; does anyone have any ideas for my story to not be a ripoff, but can give off a similar atmosphere?

Comment: The important thing to realise is that neither you nor the developers of another game decides if your games are infringing on the other's rights. That is up to the court to decide. All either party can do is argue that they are correct. You can make a farming simulator game and the developers of CoD can sue you because it's too similar to CoD. Obviously that's a bogus claim but they have a budget of billions that they can give their lawyers and you have a budget of 0.00...01% of that. You can't pay lawyers for a 3 year legal battle so guess who's gonna win?

Comment: damn, guess i should just try not to provoke activision into suing me, its not like they could sue me for millions right? But i just really love the atmosphere it gives off and want to recreate it in my own way, because games just dont feel like they used too.

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on the Writing or Worldbuilding StackExchange sites, since it sounds like it's the story you need help with at the moment, not the game mechanics. Just be sure to read their help center content and scan through similar past Q&A, so you can ask a focused, non-duplicate question within their on-topic guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that CoD did not invent most of these things. They are either things which actually exist or popular myths. Often a mix of both. They can hardly monopolize these story elements.

So a good start is to do your own research. When you dive down the rabbit hole on your own, you will find that there are a lot of interesting facts and myths around these topics which the CoD developers did *not* put in their game. And don't just focus on the Soviet Union. There are also some pretty interesting secret projects *other* states won't confirm or deny they might or might not have done during the cold war. And considering that your game is fiction, and that most of what you are going to find during your research will *also* be fiction invented by some conspiracy theorists, you can also extrapolate from what you find and invent your own.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i think i wanna focus on the mkultra brainwashing, and chemical gas concept, ive done some research on both of these topics and find it really interesting and like the the way they were addressed in the game. And yes i want to put other countries into play like germany, vietnam, korea, afghanistan, and panama. I just want my game to have a dark atmosphere to it, thank you for the answer!